# How to calculate insered number from set of numbers?

Tags: java

Hi everyone I'm beginner in java, and I have homework and don't know to do it.

I have to make a program who will help cashier with their work.
They have for return money set of 1,2,5 and 10 dollars/euros.
The program have to calculate how many of kind that money goes.
So if your entered number is 28
you have to back

```
2x10
1x5
1x2
1x1
```

I dont know even to start with code please help!

Comment: Look at the modulo operator.

Comment: If you were trying to work out the answer yourself, without a computer, what steps would you need to take?

Comment: I second khelwood's comment: IMO the whole purpose of the task is to make you think of some algorithm and since it's you who should learn that it's you who should come up with that (i.e. the step's you'd take if you were the computer). Try to implement those steps then and if you have any problems come back here and ask about those specific problems (including information of what you tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually liked that question. Even tho you should do it yourself, here is one approach.

```
int i = 28;
int tenEurosCount = i / 10;
i = i - 10 * tenEurosCount;
int fiveEurosCount = i / 5;
i = i - 5 * fiveEurosCount;
int twoEurosCount = i / 2;
i = i - 2 * twoEurosCount;
System.out.println(tenEurosCount + "x 10 \n" + fiveEurosCount + "x 5 \n" + twoEurosCount + "x 2 \n" + i + "x 1 \n");
```

Output:

```
2x 10 
1x 5 
1x 2 
1x 1
```

for i = 4

```
0x 10 
0x 5 
2x 2 
0x 1
```

for i = 42

```
4x 10 
0x 5 
1x 2 
0x 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it. I hope it helps.

```
import java.util.*;

class CalculateChange {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int returnAmount;
        int tens, fives, twos, ones;

        // User Input
        System.out.print("Enter the return amount: ");
        returnAmount = input.nextInt();

        // Calculations
        tens = returnAmount / 10;
        returnAmount = returnAmount % 10;
        fives = returnAmount / 5;
        returnAmount = returnAmount % 5;
        twos = returnAmount / 2;
        returnAmount = returnAmount % 2;
        ones = returnAmount;

        System.out.println("\nChange: ");
        System.out.println(tens + "x10");
        System.out.println(fives + "x5");
        System.out.println(twos + "x2");
        System.out.println(ones + "x1");

        input.close();
    }
}
```